# Send notification from one android device to another

Tags: android, notifications

I have one simple doubt.Is it possible to send push notification from one android device to another throw coding

Possible means please explain me with sample code

Thanks in advance

Comment: The two devices should be connected in some way, may be a socket on Wifi, or you could also ponder about sending a simple encoded SMS.